# How to make navigation aligned center?

Tags: html, css

How to align whole navigation in center of the page? including navbar-brand and items?
[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXZWd.png)
Thank you.

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
        <img src="Images/logo.png" width="65" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Почетна<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Информации</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Контакт</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok i edited my question, added photo

Comment: I recommend you read the link. It relates to the _code_ you've provided.

Comment: the CSS is missing in your question, anyway, apparently you are using Bootstrap, you should look in bootstrap site, they have several examples with navbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css:

```
.navbar{
Position: absolute;
Top:50%;
Right:50%;
Transform: translate (-50%,-50%)
}
```

Everything in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set the parent to 100% width, give the nav a specific width and set:

```css
margin: 0 auto;
```

If you are using bootstrap, please contemplate the doc:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering